# How to set timezone in tig?

Tags: git, tig

I want to set timezone to tig http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/, and I want to use Japanese timezone(+0900) in all commit, even if commiter has another timezone.

Can I set specific timezone?

```
Actual:
Thu Oct 11 01:07:31 2012 -0700
Expect:
Thu Oct 11 17:07:31 2012 +0900
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `~/.tigrc` file:

```
set show-date = local
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (tig 2.5.4) was:

Add this line to `~/.tigrc`:

```
set main-view-date-local = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time display seems to be build from the [`mkdate()` function](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/tig.c#L73), which compute the date in [one of 5 modes](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/master/tig.c#L54) (`NO`, `DEFAULT`, `LOCAL`, `RELATIVE`, `SHORT`).

So any display modification should be coded in that function.

Comment: Thanks, but how do i do next? Add ```patch``` and ```make``` at local machine?

Comment: @sanemat If by "patch" and "make", you mean patch Tig and build it locally, in order to get the right time display you want, then it could be a workaround.